# C# Syntax lambdas with curly braces

Tags: c#, syntax, lambda

```
delegate int AddDelegate(int a, int b);
AddDelegate ad = (a,b) => a+b;


AddDelegate ad = (a, b) => { return a + b; };
```

The two above versions of AddDelegate are equivalent.  Syntactically, why is it necessary
to have a semicolon before and after the `}` in the second AddDelegate? You can a compiler error `; expected` if either one is missing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe this will make it clearer:

```
AddDelegate ad = (a, b) =>
                 {
                     return a + b;
                 };
```

These semicolons effectively are for different lines.

Comment: Good answer, one's for the delegate declaration and the return statement. +1

Answer (score 8):

A *statement lambda* contains a block of *statements*... which means you need a statement terminator for each statement. Note that this is similar to anonymous methods from C# 2:

```
AddDelegate ad = delegate(int a, int b) { return a + b; };
```

Think of it as being like a method body, so:

```
AddDelegate ad = GeneratedMethod;
...
private int GeneratedMethod(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
```

Note how the final semi-colon in the original lambda expression or anonymous method is the terminator for the assignment statement. The semi-colon within the block is the terminator for the return statement.

An *expression lambda* contains only an expression... which means you *don't* need a statement terminator.

They're just two different forms of lambda expression. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) for more details. If you only have one statement and don't want to include the semi-colon, just use an expression lambda instead :)

Note that statement lambdas cannot currently be converted into expression trees.

Comment: could you expound on the importance of statement lambdas not being converted into expression trees?  This means you can't use them to query a data source, correct?

Comment: @wootscootinboogie: It means you can't use them for `Queryable` (LINQ to SQL, EF etc) - you can still use them for anything using `Enumerable` (Linq to Objects, LINQ to XML).

Comment: What keeps statement lambdas from being converted into expression trees?

Comment: @wootscootinboogie: It's just not part of what's supported by the C# compiler. Initially, expression trees couldn't even represent blocks; that was fixed by .NET 4, but there hasn't been a sufficiently compelling reason to add the requirement into the C# language. It's a pretty major difference, if you think about what you would have to be able to handle (loops, try/catch, goto etc).

Answer (score 2):

Using curly braces allow multiple statements in an lambda expression. That's why a semi colon is required to indicate the end of a statement in curly braces.